# How to execute a boolean logic stored as a string, preferably without eval()?

Tags: python, yaml, eval, pyyaml

I have the below YAML file, containing the parsing logic to match a file name:

```py
rules_container = """
file_name:
  rule_1: {module: str, method: startswith, args: [s_]}
  rule_2: {module: str, method: endswith, args: [.log]}
  logic: rule_1 and rule_2
"""
```

I load it and I get the below mapping:

```py
>>> import yaml
>>> import pprint
```

```py
>>> d_yml = yaml.safe_load(rules_container)
>>> pprint.pprint(d_yml)
{'file_name': {'logic': 'rule_1 and rule_2',
               'rule_1': {'args': ['s_'],
                          'method': 'startswith',
                          'module': 'str'},
               'rule_2': {'args': ['.log'],
                          'method': 'endswith',
                          'module': 'str'}}}
```

The below functions help me parse the above rules, and eventually I get:

- a dictionary of compiled rules
- the logic to apply the rules to a string (i.e. file name)

```py
def rule_compiler(module, method, args=None, kwargs=None):

    def str_parser(string):
        return getattr(string, method)(*args)
    
    return str_parser
```

```py
def rule_parser(container):
  
  compiled_rules = {
      k:rule_compiler(**v) for k,v in container.items() if k.startswith('rule')
  }
  
  logic = container.get('logic', None)
  
  return compiled_rules, logic
```

NOTE: I'm not using `module` and `kwargs` here, but they are used elsewhere in the configuration file, for other rules.

So, if I call `rule_parser()` on the rules' container I get this:

```py
>>> rp = rule_parser(d_yml['file_name'])
>>> print(rp)
({'rule_1': <function __main__.rule_compiler.<locals>.str_parser(string)>,
  'rule_2': <function __main__.rule_compiler.<locals>.str_parser(string)>},
 'rule_1 and rule_2')
```

If I try to parse a string with every single rule, they work as expected:

```py
>>> fname = 's_test.out'
```

```py
>>> rp[0]['rule_1'](fname)
True
>>> rp[0]['rule_2'](fname)
False
```

I want to apply the logic defined by the "logic" and get this:

```py
>>> rp[0]['rule_1'](fname) and rp[0]['rule_2'](fname)
False
```

I've already thought of a way of doing this by parsing the string containing the boolean logic, transform it into something simimlar to the above, and then call `eval()` on it.

Can you think of any other way not involving `eval()`?

NOTE: there might be more than two rules, so replacing the logic with a simple "and/or" and then using some kind of `if` statement to determine which one to apply wouldn't work either.

NOTE: using regular expressions and remove the need for multiple rules altogether is not an option in this specific case.

Thanks!

Comment: You might have luck with `ast.literal_eval(...)` (not checked).

Comment: The long-form Right Way is to build a parser that reads the language you care about, generates an AST, and then build implementations of the AST nodes. Take a university-level compiler design class, and you'll be ready by the end of it. I'm not convinced that this is appropriate scope for a Stack Overflow question, however. Any decent parser generator will let you set up appropriate precedence rules, &c.

Comment: @Jan, this is certainly not a literal. I would not expect `literal_eval` to work.

Comment: @Jan I get a `ValueError: malformed node or string` with `ast.literal_eval()`. Thanks for your input, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea, using [`pandas.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html), not sure how much it suits your case.

```
import pandas as pd

fname = 's_test.out'
rule, logic = rp

def apply_rule(rule_dict: dict, fname: str) -> dict:
    return {rule: func(fname) 
        for rule, func in rule_dict.items()}

print(pd.eval(logic, local_dict = apply_rule(rule, fname)))
```

Output:

```
False
```

Comment: This seems to work nicely. I don't have to parse/modify the string provided through the  `logic` key and worry about creating a valid expression to be executed via `eval()`. Moreover, if I try to pass a "dangerous" string via `logic` (e.g. `"__import__('os').listdir('.')"`) I get an exception `ValueError: "__import__" is not a supported function`. So, apart from the fact I have to import `pandas`, I don't see any drawbacks.

Comment: I haven't been able to make it work using the `boolean.py` library, and I'm not going to build a parser. I understand there are still some risks by using `pd.eval()`. Although, for now it looks safer - and more versatile - than `eval()`. So' I'm going to pick this as the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer could span anywhere from using a library like [boolean.py](https://github.com/bastikr/boolean.py) to parse your strings (less flexible, probably easiest choice other than `eval`) to reading up on [lexers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and [parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Parser) and implementing one from scratch or with a parser generating software (most flexible, but difficult and time-consuming). In this case I'd probably recommend starting with a library specifically built for evaluating boolean expressions and, if that doesn't work, try something more involved.

Edit: I should note that you *could* use `eval` if there are no entry points for users to inject malicious code, you properly sanitize the eval string, etc. - probably not worth your time, but worth considering if the other options don't suit your needs.

Comment: I like the idea of using [boolean.py](https://github.com/bastikr/boolean.py). I've been trying to make it work, but I always end up in a situation where I have to create variables dynamically, based on my rules' names. So, I'm back at square one, only with a different [bad practice](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Comment: Could you maybe use a dictionary to dynamically set "variable" names or create a handful of variables in advance and set those to the values you need?

Comment: My understanding about the usage of this library is that I need to get to a point where I have something like `rule_1, rule_2 = algebra.symbols(True, False)`, where `True` and `False` are the outcomes of the `startswith()` and `endswith()` methods respectively. To get there, I need to make the rules' names - which can change - part of the function's namespace. So, I'm creating variables dynamically. Otherwise, the string contained in `logic` is not going to work anymore as is.

Comment: And even if I were able to get to the point were rules' names becomes part of the local namespace, I still would not be able to get the expected outcome out of this library. In fact, if I do `algebra.parse(logic) == [True|False|TRUE|FALSE]` I always get `FALSE`.